# Compiling on Mac

Tags: c, gcc, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I am brand new to this forum, and have just begun to learn C. The book I am going through wants me to compile the code that was written. I have a file "cards.c", I am on a Mac, have Xcode installed, downloaded gcc from Apple and installed it.

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

When I type:

```
gcc cards.c -o cards
```

I get:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'cards.c'
clang: error: no input files
```

I have tried going to Xcode downloads to install Xcode's Command Line Tools, it doesn't show up there, maybe I have a newer version?

I cannot figure out how to compile this, any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Does the cards.c file need to be in a specific folder somewhere?

Comment: First to learn: **C is not C++ is not C!** Do not add tags for one language for questions about the other.

Comment: Second: Please take the [tour]

Comment: Probably a silly question but have you `cd`-ed into the directory where your cards.c file is before typing `gcc cards.c -o cards` in the command line?

Comment: No, I have not `cd` -ed into the directory, what you see is what I've done, not sure how to do that. The beginner book I am using only gave me that code. How do I go about that? @Caninonos

Comment: Ok, then that's your problem. You should learn to use a couple basic commands before trying to compile in the command line (mainly `cd` and `ls`). Basically, `cd` stands for "change directory" (gcc will look for "cards.c" in the current directory, and you have to change the current directory with `cd` beforehand), `ls` stands for "list" (and list the files/directories in the current directory). A quick google search gave me [this](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0020.php) for the basics (Edit: most of the commands are similar on Mac OS and Linux distributions).